# Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\times\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(v,w)=w^{T}Av$, then which of the following are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\times\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(v,w)=w^{T}Av$, then which of the following are true?
>
> 1. There exists an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ such that $Av$ is perpendicular to $v$.
> 2. The set $S=\{v\in\mathbb{R}| f(v,v)=0\}$ is a nonzero subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$.
> 3. If $v,w\in \mathbb{R^2}$ are nonzero vectors such that $f(v,v)=0=f(w,w)$ then $v$ is a scalar multiple of $w$.
> 4. For every $v\in \mathbb{R^2}$, there eists a nonzero $w\in \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $f(v,w)=0.$

---

**My try:**

Option 1 is easy to conclude by calculating the eigenvalues of $A$ and then eigenvectors. So 1 is true.

For option 2, $f(v,v)=0\implies v^TAv=0$, where $v=(v_1,v_2)^T$. Doing some calculations, I got $v_1=\pm v_2$, from which I see that any vectors which have either both components same or opposite in sign will satisfy the given condition. So $S=\alpha\{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, scalar. So does this implies option 2 is also correct? because this is a nonzero subspace. But answer says only option 1 is correct.

Also I am confused with option 3 and 4. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: In what way is $1$ true?  Which **eigenvector** of $A$ satisfies $v^TAv = 0$?

Comment: Sorry didn't see it. You are right. @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again: with $\;v=(v_1,v_2)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ , we get

$$0=f(v,v)=(v_1\;v_2)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}\binom{v_1}{v_2}=(v_1\;-v_2)\binom{v_1}{v_2}=v_1^2-v_2^2\implies v_1=\pm v_2$$

and then $\;S\;$ is not even a subspace ( Why? You can also take a geometric peek at this: $\;S\;$ is the union of the lines $\;y=x\;,\;\;y=-x\;$ )

With the above you can also answer (3), and for (4):

$$f(v,w)=(v_1\;v_2)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!-1\end{pmatrix}\binom{w_1}{w_2}=(v_1\;v_2)\binom{\;w_1}{\!-w_2}=v_1w_1-v_2w_2$$

Thus, for given $\;v=\binom{v_1}{v_2}\;$, we can find $\;w=\binom{w_1}{w_2}\;$ s.t. $\;f(v,w)=0\;$ iff $\;v_1w_1=v_2w_2\;$ . Can you now argue why this is true? Maybe doing cases can help.

Comment: As @Omnomnomnom pointed out, option 1 is not true. Can you please give me a hint why?

Comment: Oh sorry got it.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Nice you got it.

Comment: I am little bit confused with option 4. You said doing cases can help, what cases? Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan For example, suppose $\;v_1=0\;$ , then we'd get $$0=v_1w_1=v_2w_2\implies w_2=0\;$$ so if we have $\;v=(0,v_2)\;$, then with $\;w=(w_1,0)\;$ we'll get $\;f(v,w)=0\;$ . Or if $\;v_1,v_2\neq0\;$ , then $$v_1w_1=v_2w_2\implies w_1=\frac{v_2}{v_1}w_2$$ so with $\;w=\left(\frac{v_2}{v_1}w_2,\,w_2\right)\;$ we get $\;f(v,w)=0\;$ , and etc.